# Issue with using php and sql to add data to datables

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

So I'm trying to use php and mysql to put data in my datatables on my website. I wrote some code at the top of my file to confirm that I am accessing my database correctly. The table is displayed correctly when i manually entered some data, but with my php code, the table says "No data available in table". Any thoughts on whats wrong with my php?

```
    $q = "SELECT tickets.ticket_id, tickets.section, tickets.row, tickets.price, users.first_name as first_name, users.last_name as last_name 
          FROM tickets 
          LEFT JOIN users 
          ON tickets.seller_id = users.umid
          Where(tickets.game_id = '$g')";

    $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);



     <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Section</th>
           <th>Row</th>
           <th>Price</th>
           <th>Seller</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>

        <?php
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

           echo '
              <tr>
                 <td>'.$row["section"].'</td>
                 <td>'.$row["row"].'</td>
                 <td>'.$row["price"].'</td>
                 <td>'.$row["first_name"]. " ". $row["last_name"]. '</td>
              </tr>
              ';
           }
        ?>

     </tbody>
  </table>
```

[This is what the table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqANY.jpg)

[Link to the webpage](http://michmarket.com/buy-ticket?id=F1)

Comment: can you get any error while running..?

Comment: Wheres the conditional for `No data available in table`?

Comment: show me the content of $r

Comment: Don't use `@`, that just hides useful errors from you.

Comment: i updated my code in the post

Comment: Still no conditional, where does the `no data available` come from?

Comment: do you mind explaining why i shouldn't use @, @chris85?

Comment: `@` suppresses errors, if your query is erring you should know about it (and correct it).

Comment: I'm assuming that the "no data available" is something that is in the datatables plugin. I didn't code anything to output that.

Comment: So when you view the source `<tbody>` is empty?

Comment: I don't think it is an issue with accessing my database though. At  the top of my webpage (I didn't show this code in the post) I echo some of the values from my database and they show up on the webpage.

Comment: `$name = $first_name . " " . $last_name;` won't work as you expect, you need to fetch there, and use the indices.

Comment: Yes, when i view the source <tbody> is empty

Comment: What's `var_dump($r);` and what happens when the `@` is removed?

Comment: Is data displayed in the table if you remove the WHERE clause from the query?

Comment: I'm not sure what the var_dump($r) is. When i remove @, nothing changes. When i remove WHERE, nothing else changes withing the table.

Comment: Inside the table row is not closed properly. close with </tr> tag.

Comment: you're right, but even after i fix that, the data still wont display

Comment: @ChaseRun finally you found the error right .?

Comment: @Sahathulla no, I fixed the </tr> but the data still wont display

Comment: @ChaseRun You need to add a closing PHP tag (`?>`) before your `<table>` HTML tag.

Comment: @ChaseRun I am not saying about that. you changed your answer from $row["name"] to $row["first_name"]. " ". $row["last_name"]. It fixes your error right.?

Comment: @TheodoreBrown in my full code, I have all of my php tags closed.

Comment: @Sahathulla i think it fixed my issue, but I'm not 100% sure since nothing is being displayed. i would assume that it would fix the issue though

Comment: @ChaseRun i checked you code $name = $first_name . " " . $last_name this code has the error without retrieving firstname and lastname you concatenate the string thats the issue. Now you fixed correctly. Anymore error let me know.

Comment: If you view source, is the `<tbody>` element still empty?

Comment: @TheodoreBrown yes, when i view the source <tbody> is still empty

Comment: Can you echo your query and check with your database tables is it working fine.?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the SQL statement in $q works properly? Because without a value in $g (which your script seems to have omitted), the SQL statement will look for records where game_id = '' (or presumably 0 if it's a numeric field).

Comment: in my full code, i test that my query works correctly by printing one of the rows of my database table at the top of the page. If you check my webpage and my source code, it shows that the query is correct

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. I looped through my row earlier in my code, so when i wanted to put the info in the table, it was at the end of the array.